# MUI and Preact in typescript express app, getting console error "prop `children` supplied to `InnerThemeProvider`, expected a ReactNode."

Tags: typescript, webpack, material-ui, preact

I'm implementing a Preact app and would like to use MUI. Everything seems to be referencing appropriately in VSCode, but when I try to access it on the browser nothing gets rendered and this console error pops up:

```
react-jsx-runtime.development.js:87 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `InnerThemeProvider`, expected a ReactNode.
 at InnerThemeProvider (http://localhost:8080/main.js:54463:70)
 printWarning   @   react-jsx-runtime.development.js:87
 error  @   react-jsx-runtime.development.js:61
 checkPropTypes @   react-jsx-runtime.development.js:631
 validatePropTypes  @   react-jsx-runtime.development.js:1164
 jsxWithValidation  @   react-jsx-runtime.development.js:1284
 jsxWithValidationDynamic   @   react-jsx-runtime.development.js:1301
 ThemeProvider  @   ThemeProvider.js:34
 M  @   preact.js:1
 I  @   preact.js:1
 b  @   preact.js:1
 I  @   preact.js:1
 b  @   preact.js:1
 I  @   preact.js:1
 N  @   preact.js:1
 (anonymous)    @   main.tsx:24
 (anonymous)    @   main.tsx:24
 (anonymous)    @   main.tsx:24
```

I've tried messing around on webpack and tsconfig, but honestly unless I can find it online I'm just guessing, and it doesn't look like anyone else is having this exact problem.  I'm thinking it has to be an aliasing thing since it's mentioning react stuff.

The file structure is this:

```
.
├── index.ts
├── main.pug
├── main.tsx
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

There's only 6 small files of interest (I've cut it down as much as I know how):

1. index.ts: the file that runs the server

```
import express = require("express");
import { Server } from 'http';
import { Application, Request, Response } from "express";

const PORT = 8080;

const setupServer: () => Promise<void> = async () => {
    let app = express();
    const http = new Server(app);
    
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.static(__dirname));

    // setup pug template engine
    app.engine("pug", require("pug").__express);
    app.set("views",__dirname);

    app.get("*", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        res.render("./main.pug");
    });

    // console.log that your server is up and listening
    http.listen(PORT, function() {
        console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
    });
};
setupServer();
```

2. main.tsx: the beahvior file referenced by the pug file

```
import { h, render } from "preact";
import { Button, createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material';
import { red } from '@mui/material/colors';

const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        main: red[500],
      },
    },
});

function Main() {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Button variant="contained">Hello World</Button>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
};
render(<Main />, document.body);
```

3. webpack.config.js

```
"use strict";
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = env => {

    // shared by all bundle configs
    const baseConfig = {
        mode: "development",
        devtool: "source-map",
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".js", ".json", ".ts", ".tsx"],
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    use: 'ts-loader',
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                },
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: ["babel-loader"]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
                }
            ]
        }
    };

    // client config
    const clientMainBundleConfig = merge(baseConfig,{
        name: 'main',
        entry: { 'main': __dirname + "/main.tsx" },
        target: 'web',
        output: {
            path:  __dirname,
            filename: "[name].js"
        },
        resolve: {
            alias: { 
                "preact/hooks": require.resolve('preact/hooks'),
                "preact": require.resolve('preact')
            }
        }
    });

    // the config for the index file on server side
    const serverBundleConfig = merge(baseConfig,{
        target: 'node',
        name: 'index',
        externals: [nodeExternals()],
        entry: { 'index':  __dirname + "/index.ts" },
        output: {
            path:  __dirname,
            filename: "[name].js"
        },
    });

    return [serverBundleConfig,clientMainBundleConfig];
};
```

4. tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",                           
    "jsxFactory": "h",                        
    "jsxFragmentFactory": "Fragment",         
    "baseUrl": "./",                   
    "target": "es6",                               
    "module": "commonjs",                                                     
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,      
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "paths": {                              
      "react": ["./node_modules/preact/compat"],
      "react-dom": ["./node_modules/preact/compat"]
    },             
  },
  "exclude":[
    "./node_modules"
  ]
}
```

5. package.json

```
{
  "name": "preact-mui",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --stats-error-details",
    "start": "node ./index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/core": "^11.0.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.15",
    "@types/express-session": "^1.17.5",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.15",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "http": "^0.0.1-security",
    "preact": "^10.11.3",
    "preact-cli": "^3.4.1",
    "preact-render-to-string": "^5.2.6",
    "preact-router": "^4.1.0",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.2",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

6. main.pug (I guess this isn't really interesting but just for completeness):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
html(lang="en")
  head
    meta(charset="utf-8")
    meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible", content="IE=edge")
    meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1")
  body.container-fluid
    div#mainDiv
    script(type='text/javascript', src="./main.js").
```

I tried aliasing react and react-dom towards preact/compat, hoping that since it's mentioning react if I just redirect it back towards preact then it would automagically correct itself, but low and behold that didn't work.
Then I tried updating the tsconfig.json to include the below per the [mui guide](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/typescript/):

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    ...
```

But still nothing changed.

Nothing's really showing up on google/SO so not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've misunderstood what aliasing is.

Aliasing is giving X when Y is asked for. In your code, you're aliasing `preact` and `preact/hooks` to themselves, which does nothing at all.

Now, you need to alias as React and Preact components are not the same shape;  you cannot pass a React component to Preact without errors being thrown (or vice versa). `preact/compat` is a translation layer that facilitates doing this, however.

You need to add this into your base config:

```js
resolve: {
    alias: { 
        "react": "preact/compat",
        "react-dom/test-utils": "preact/test-utils",
        "react-dom": "preact/compat",     // Must be below test-utils
        "react/jsx-runtime": "preact/jsx-runtime"
    }
 }
```

> https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/getting-started#aliasing-in-webpack

Comment: a god in the form of a stack-overflow account